# HTTP Status 404 (Tomcat) or 503 (J2EE) while launching JSP file after renaming project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, web.xml

I know there's plenty of topics like that, but none of solutions that I found worked for me.

I'm trying to run one of my JSP files on server, but I'm getting errors like in topic's title. What's really bothering me is that it worked perfectly just minutes ago, but then I got brilliant idea of changing project's name. Since then nothing is working. I tried to remove project and import it again, I tried different servers (Tomcat and J2EE Preview - on second one I get error 503), I tried changing Tomcat's location and making new fresh servers. Still nothing. My JSP files are in WebContent folder. Below is my web.xml file, but I don't think there's anything wrong with it, as it was working earlier. Also that's why I don't know what to post, cause it seems like problem with Eclipse. Although my previous project with jsp is working perfectly, so it's even more confusing. The path seems to be ok, as it's `http://localhost:8080/projectName/index.jsp`

Any idea how to fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern> //no difference with .jsp - previously it worked with .jsf
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
    <param-value>C:/upload/</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use tomcat as server, you should check the server.xml file in "Servers" project. Find tag `<context>`, something like `<Context docBase="SpringRmiTest" path="/SpringRmiTest" .../>`, mostly at the end of the file. Make sure this config is suit for for project name and location.

Comment: In eclipse, right click on your project, open the properties dialog, scroll down to the bottom, there is an option "Web project settings", check if the "Context root" is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may look silly but works sometimes. Give it a shot. In the TOMCAT server, try removing and re-adding your project again. Restart the server after adding.

Also, make sure that you are using the correct server port and your jsp is in WEB-INF folder.

Comment: I've already tried removing and re-adding few times. I even removed whole server and created it again, still nothing. Port is correct (default 8080), also I read that jsp files should be in WebContent folder. But still I tried to copy them to WEB-INF, it's not working either.